# Fetching and setting images in listView via HTTP

Tags: android, eclipse, http, listview

I am making an app that loads images via internet to a ListView. It is built on sdk 15 with an minimum of 8. Everything works fine if i run it on an emulator with version 8, but if i run it on anything with an sdk of 11 and up the app fails to set the images in the ListView and it then only displays an empty list. Logcat doesn't give anything on this.

I haven't had any succes finding an article addressing this issue, but i think it most be something with the HTTP that is suppose to get the images from the internet, but i don't understand why they don't work on the newer versions of android.

My code looks like this.

EDIT UPDATED CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
ListView listView;
TextView footer;
int offset = 0;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
View v;
String responseBody;
HttpResponse r;
HttpEntity e;
String searchUrl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            tumblrs = getTumblrs();
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout,
                    null);
            footer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFoot);
            listView.addFooterView(v);
            listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem));

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new GetChicks().execute();
        footer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new loadMoreListView().execute();
            }
        });

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.nonet);

    }

}

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tumblr> {

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId) {
        super(context, imageViewResourceId, tumblrs);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);

        }

        Tumblr tumblr = tumblrs.get(position);
        if (tumblr != null) {

            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(GetImage_usingURl(urls[position]));

            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}

String[] urls = new String[] { "url1", "url2", "url2" };

public Bitmap GetImage_usingURl(String BitmapUrl) {
    try {
        Log.d("Image Download State", " Open Stream For : " + BitmapUrl);
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(BitmapUrl).openStream();
        Log.d("Image Download State", " Start Decode");

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Tumblr> getTumblrs() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=rTZsymOWtMudbb5tql2U20qQ5ooYLPYVNnL3COPpO2qBHDxJUu&limit=2&offset=0";

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>();
    return tumblrs;
}

private class GetChicks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Chicks coming up..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

        HttpResponse r = null;
        try {
            r = client.execute(get);
            int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                e = r.getEntity();
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

            JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response")
                    .getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(
                        "photos");
                for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
                    String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes")
                            .getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

                    Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
                    tumblrs.add(tumblr);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // Setting new scroll position
        listView.setSelectionFromTop(0, 0);
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}

public class Tumblr {

    public String image_url;

    public Tumblr(String url) {

        this.image_url = url;

    }
}

private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("More chicks coming up..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // increment current page
        offset += 2;

        // Next page request
        tumblrs.clear();
        String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=rTZsymOWtMudbb5tql2U20qQ5ooYLPYVNnL3COPpO2qBHDxJUu&limit=2&offset="
                + offset;
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

        HttpResponse r = null;
        try {
            r = client.execute(get);
            int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

            JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response")
                    .getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(
                        "photos");
                for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
                    String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes")
                            .getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

                    Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
                    tumblrs.add(tumblr);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // Setting new scroll position
        listView.setSelectionFromTop(0, 0);
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutUs:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.example.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);

        break;
    case R.id.refresh:
        Intent f = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(f);
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

 }
```

LOG

```
 10-09 13:21:57.923: D/Image Download State(888):  Open Stream For : url1
 10-09 13:21:57.923: E/Error(888): Protocol not found: url1
 10-09 13:21:58.013: D/Image Download State(888):  Open Stream For : url2
 10-09 13:21:58.033: E/Error(888): Protocol not found: url2
 10-09 13:21:58.113: D/Image Download State(888):  Open Stream For : url1
 10-09 13:21:58.123: E/Error(888): Protocol not found: url1
 10-09 13:21:58.153: D/Image Download State(888):  Open Stream For : url2
 10-09 13:21:58.153: E/Error(888): Protocol not found: url2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Images From internet Try this Could Help you:

if you want to download when you create adapter .

```
String[] urls=new String[]{"url1","url2","url2"}

public Bitmap GetImage_usingURl(String url){
  try {
                Log.d("Image Download State", " Open Stream For : "
                        + url);
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                Log.d("Image Download State", " Start Decode");

               return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                 return null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

And When You Create Adapet Just Use :

```
image.setImageBitmap(GetImage_usingURl(urls[position]);
```

---

**Important** Thing For Your Project You Have To Get Policy When You using HTTP its Only For API 9 or higher so i check VERSION.SDK_INT First .

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

if you don't set **StrictMode** you program maybe crash.

### Set This Code Before Everything .

Your Errors Its :
In getView You Try To Check **img!=null** but you forget its create now and its already null
so compiler never get in and set your images , This is first thing .

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use your "way 2" but it still does'nt work for me. I have added the updated code in the question, can you see if I have used it the right way?

Comment: Okay , I Edit My Answer With New Changes Must Be There is important thing with API 9 or higher "Policy" When Using HTTP . And One Error I found it in your code , hope it help

Comment: I have tried to implement your code, but it is still not working for me. I have updated the code in the question, can you see what i am doing wrong?

Comment: i tell you remove  if (image != null)  from getView()

Comment: It still wont work for me. Now the log gives me an error. I have included the log in my question.

Comment: of course there is an error , i give you urls[] as example you should set image like this :
image.setImageBitmap(GetImage_usingURl(tumblr.image_url));